# HTTP "Partial" Get Request Message in Java

Tags: java, url, arrays, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I need to use a HTTP "Partial Get Request message in Java, but I could not find any answers on internet.

Actually, I know how to send a "get" message but I don't know how to send a "partial get" one.

The code below shows some information:

```
      else if(args.length == 0){ // 5 OLACAK
            con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

            fromURL = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream(), bufSize);
            toFile = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), bufSize);

            if(con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

                byte startRange =  0; //Byte.parseByte(args[3]);
                byte finishRange =  25;//Byte.parseByte(args[4]);

                if(startRange < 0 || finishRange > ((byte)con.getContentLength())
                        || startRange > finishRange){
                    System.out.println("Range is not OK.");
                }else{                     

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //
                // I need to send a partial get message here 
                // Range should in between [startRange, finishRange]
                //
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is all over the place, so its hard to figure out where you are in your own personal research. But lets assume you already know that the server side resource supports range requests - to send a partial GET you just need to do two things:

1. Include a `Range:` header with the start and end of the range you are seeking
2. Handle the response, noting that the server ***should*** return a status code of '206 - Partial Content'

Some pseudocode:

```
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.addRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=0-25");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        conn.getOutputStream()));
if(conn.getResponseCode() == 206) {
    // process stream here
}
```

Comment: In java, how could I add a range to **_setRequestMethod()_**.
I could not figure out that part. 
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You don't add it to `setRequestMethod`, you specify a `Range:` header (which I've already illustrated how to do in the answer).

Comment: That pseudocode is really helpful, thanks for your reply again.